# load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is deprecated

Tags: php, wordpress

my wordpress site and admin site not working.
some day ago i check site working fine but from last 2 days it shows show the error.

`Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.7 with no alternative available. in /var/www/html/c_project/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3844`

`Notice: Undefined variable: mobile in /var/www/html/c_project/wp-content/plugins/smooth-page-scroll-to-top/smooth_scroll.php on line 24`

`Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in AboutMeWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /var/www/html/c_project/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3718`

`Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in AdsenseWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /var/www/html/c_project/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3718`

`Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in AdvWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /var/www/html/c_project/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3718`

`Notice: Undefined index: act in /var/www/html/c_project/wp-content/plugins/image-captcha/image-captcha.php on line 69`

`Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/c_project/wp-content/themes/Divi/epanel/shortcodes/shortcodes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/c_project/wp-content/themes/Divi/functions.php on line 1252`

`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/c_project/wp-content/themes/Divi/epanel/shortcodes/shortcodes.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/xphoto/models/dffa') in /var/www/html/c_project/wp-content/themes/Divi/functions.php on line 1252`

how can i solve this error.?

Please suggest me.

Comment: your code has become outdated somehow. May be rollbacked theme or something ?

Comment: i agree with you. but i can not open admin side, it shows same error above

Comment: If you have backup of your theme restore it. If you have not done any modifications to the theme itself you can put a fresh copy in there too. Use ftp or cpanel